# Issue with \n while converting DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, .net

I am storing below data in DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1, "hiuhohihiukkk\nkngfgkh", "Hongkong", "China");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Stella", "Newyork", "US");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Stone", "Hongkong", "China");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "Curt", "Redmond", "US");
dt.Rows.Add(5, "Brady", "Redmond", "US");
```

As given in the first row of DataTable, we have value as `"hiuhohihiukkk\nkngfgkh"` which contains \n in it. Now while exporting this data to csv file, I am getting data as below which is incorrect.

[image]

Actually, my data should look like below

[image]

How can I resolve issue?

**Update 1:**

As shown below, I am converting DataTable to MemoryStream. I have also followed [AzureDataLakeGen2-CreateFileAsync](https://github.com/magicheron/AzureDataLakeGen2-SDK) article for creating csv file.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the csv export code?

Comment: Where's the code that creates the CSV file? Fields that contain newlines or delimiters should be quoted. Libraries like CsvHelper take care of this already. If you use your own code you should take care of quoting yourself.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create a CSV file, it just adds some data to a DataTable. If you inspect the DataTable you'll see there's nothing wrong with the data. It's the code that generates the CSV file that fails to quote some fields

Comment: I took lines if number of columns < expected, join row below.. worked well for me

Comment: can be related which encoding you use while opening csv file

Comment: added more code.Kindly check

Comment: How can I quote fields.Could you please provide some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by adding below code. If any field value contains any characters given below, then append string with `"\""` as below

```
            char[] CHARACTERS_THAT_MUST_BE_QUOTED = { ',', '"', '\r', '\n'};
            string s = "hiuhohihiukkk\nkngfgkh";
            if (s.IndexOfAny(CHARACTERS_THAT_MUST_BE_QUOTED) > -1) s=  "\"" + s + "\"";
            dt.Rows.Add(1,  s, "Hongkong", "China");
```